# How to rbind two data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have these datasets:

```
emp1<- data.frame(emp_id = c (1:5), emp_name = c("Ri","Dn","Mi","Ry","Gy"),
  salary = c(63,52,6,72,85),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
emp2<- data.frame(emp_id = c (1:5), salary = c(63,52,6,72,85),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to rbind  emp1 and  emp2 only for the common columns and ignore the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `intersect` to find the common columns and `rbind` them.

```
cols <- intersect(names(emp1), names(emp2))
rbind(emp1[cols], emp2[cols])

#   emp_id salary
#1       1     63
#2       2     52
#3       3      6
#4       4     72
#5       5     85
#6       1     63
#7       2     52
#8       3      6
#9       4     72
#10      5     85
```